# Display woocommerce review count next to star rating

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce star rating without reviews count.

[image]

Modified Woocommerce star rating with reviews count.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Woocommerce already displays reviews count next to star rating in single product page. But on shop and archives page it displays only star rating. Follow the below steps to display star rating count even on shop and archives pages.

Step 1) Create a new folder in your theme’s root and name it ‘woocommerce’

Step 2) Create a new folder in the newly created ‘woocommerce’ folder and name it ‘loop’

**Step 3) Add ‘rating.php’ file to the newly created ‘loop’ folder**

Now your directory would look something like this

> /public_html/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/woocommerce/loop

Add the below code to the newly created ‘rating.php’ and customize it according to your need.

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Rating
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/rating.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'no' ) {
    return;
}

$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
$review_count = $product->get_review_count();
$average      = $product->get_average_rating();

if ( $rating_count >= 0 ) : ?>

            <?php echo wc_get_rating_html($average, $rating_count); ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ): ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s',$review_count,'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a><?php endif ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

In case this doesn’t work

Add ‘templates’ folder in ‘woocommerce’ folder and then add ‘loop’ folder in ‘templates’ folder.

Now the directory would look like this

> /public_html/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/woocommerce/templates/loop

Comment: can you  please how i can call review counting number into twc  woocommerce plugin file so its will show number of the total review on each product

Answer (score -1):

In theory this would be perfect but I think the instructions are missing a step to call the review count as I tried both ways and none displayed the reviews count number only the stars

Moving the loop folder into the woocommerce active theme seems to have resolved the count issue but I would like it next to the stars not underneath it. How would I fix that ?

[image: see image attached]