# How to use a Woocommerce template code into theme's functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I want to show the counting number of reviews on each woocommerce products so I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383613/display-woocommerce-review-count-next-to-star-rating) and its working for all the products as well.

but I have also added recent reviews section with the help of another plugin. where the counting number not showing.

The reason is that the plugin not found the ratting.php code so i want to know how i can use the rating.php code into theme functions.php file. In other words, words, How i can convert this code like functions so i can use this into functions.php file

here is the code of rating.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Rating
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/rating.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'no' ) {
    return;
}

$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
$review_count = $product->get_review_count();
$average      = $product->get_average_rating();

if ( $rating_count >= 0 ) : ?>

            <?php echo wc_get_rating_html($average, $rating_count); ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ): ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s',$review_count,'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a><?php endif ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to do the what he added at the end after the code?

Comment: yes but its showing nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the code in a function as a shortcode with an **`id`** argument *(the product id)*:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_rating', 'display_product_rating' );
function display_product_rating( $atts ){
    // Shortcode attributes (default)
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '0',
    ), $atts, 'product_rating' );

    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'no' )
        return; // Exit

    global $product, $post;

    if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_product') ){
        $product_id   = $atts['id'] > 0 ? $atts['id'] : get_the_id();
        $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_product') ) 
            return; // Exit
    }

    $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
    $review_count = $product->get_review_count();
    $average      = $product->get_average_rating();
    $output       = '';

    if ( $rating_count >= 0 ) {
        $output .= wc_get_rating_html($average, $rating_count);
        if ( comments_open() ) {
            $fcount = $printf( _n( '%s',$review_count,'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' );
            $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">('.$fcount.')</a>';
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE EXAMPLES:**

1) In a WordPress text editor of a post or a page, defining the **`id`** argument *(the product Id)*:

```
[product_rating id='37']
```

2) In a some php code with a **dynamic `$product_id`** variable *(the product ID)*:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[product_rating id='$product_id']" );
```

3) Inside the product loop of a `WP_Query` or a `WC_Product_Query`:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[product_rating]" );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not working in my case i want something this https://prnt.sc/kyw1xp like into here  https://prnt.sc/kyw29s

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj Sorry but I can't help you more than that…

Comment: i just want to use this code work into the another plugin   if ( $rating_count > 0 ) : ?>

 <div class="woocommerce-product-rating">
  <?php echo wc_get_rating_html( $average, $rating_count ); ?>
  <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a><?php endif ?>
 </div>

<?php endif; ?>

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj You will have to find the way yourself.

Comment: I have tried everything but its not working ok thanks for help lets see what i can do